# es6 extend parent class undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 very simple classes one is a parent class `Calendar` the other the child class `MonthCalendar`:

calendar.js:

```
import MonthCalendar from './month-calendar';

export default class Calendar {
  constructor() {
    this.date = new Date();
  }

  displayMonthCalendar(){
    var mcal = new MonthCalendar();
    mcal.generate();
  }
}

var cal = new Calendar();
cal.displayMonthCalendar();
```

month-calendar.js:

```
import Calendar from './calendar';

export default class MonthCalendar extends Calendar {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  generate() {
    alert('working');
  }
}
```

When I try running this I keep getting the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined`

It's telling me `Calendar` is undefined; however if I don't extend `Calendar` and use it inside the `generate()` method it is not undefined:

month-calendar.js:

```
import Calendar from './calendar';

export default class MonthCalendar {
  generate() {
    console.log(new Calendar());
  }
}
```

That throws no error.

Comment: That's because of the circular reference

Comment: @Amit Is there any way around this? Or is this just how es6 is going to be?

Comment: There are *hacks* around this, such as "indirect export" (make the exported value a return value in an exported function), but I don't think there's a "real" solution. BTW, ES2015 is finalized.

Comment: @Amit any examples or links of how to go about this?

Comment: Why does `Calendar` know about `MonthCalendar` in the first place?

Comment: @FelixKling Because it needs to instantiate a new MonthCalendar object. Calendar has 2 subclasses `WeekCalendar` and `MonthCalendar`. So when I want to display a `MonthCalendar` I instantiate a new `MonthCalendar` object and generate it same goes for the`WeekCalendar`

Comment: Why does *it* have to do it? Why not have a factory that does that? Or why cannot the code who actually needs the calendar instantiate the correct subclass? I'd recommend to restructure your code to avoid the circular dependency.

Comment: @FelixKling Both WeekCalendar and MonthCalendar need to keep in sync the value of `this.date` If I create a new instance of `MonthCalendar` and then a new instance of `WeekCalendar` `this.date` will not have the same value

Comment: Seems like you might want a "DateStore" or something that both calendars are referencing. DateStore would contain the data needed by both calendars.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you this does seem like the best option