# Node.js v6.2.0 class extends is not a function error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

So I'm trying to extend a class in node js and the compiler keeps returning the following error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a function or null
```

I checked that I was exporting the class correctly and I am, any ideas? I'll post my code below:

#### /handler/venue.js:

```
var VenueViews = require('../views/venue'); // If I remove this the error will dissapear (as expected)
class Venue {
  constructor(data) {
    this.setDataHere = data;
  }

  main () {
   var View = new VenueViews(); // This doesn't run
  }


}

module.exports = Venue;
```

#### /views/venue.js:

```
var Venue = require('../handlers/venue');
console.log  (Venue) // This returns {} ???

class VenueViews extends Venue {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

module.exports = VenueViews;
```

I know that node supports these `es6 features`, so I'm unsure why they aren't working?

#### Edit:

I'm not sure if this is suppose to happen but, when I log my `Venue` require it returns an empty object `{}`.

```
console.log  (Venue) // This returns {} ???
```

Comment: Some had the same issue earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37307471/218196 . Problem: circular reference. Solution: Find a way to avoid circular reference.

Comment: What's circular about my code though? I'm simply wanting to inherit all the `Venue` class properties and use them in the `VenueViews` class. @FelixKling

Comment: *"What's circular about my code though? "* `/views/venue.js` imports `/handler/venue.js` which imports `/views/venue.js` which imports `/handler/venue.js` .... I could go on :P

Comment: Your view should not inherit from the venue.

Comment: Yeah now I see it! @FelixKling Wasn't paying attention :P

Comment: it should be when you log itm output should like this
```sh
[Function: Venue]
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

So it turns out I had a circular reference in my code, where I was `importing` the class that was extending, into the class that itself was extending (tongue twister :P).

The obvious fix was to simply remove the `extends` reference and find another way of doing what I was trying to achieve. In my case it was passing the `Venue` class properties down into the `VenueViews` constructor.

E.g `var x = VenueViews(this)`

Comment: > importing the class that was extending, into the class that itself was extending

Sounds like a sign of bad design to me. Not necesserly, but think about it.

In my case, I had a base class B in one file, and derived classes X, Y, Z in other files. Then in the sam file where B is, I had another class M which uses X,Y and Z. I just moved B to a separate file.

Answer (score 6):

In my instance, it was the same issue as @James111 was experiencing (circular import) due to a factory pattern I was trying to set up in Typescript. My fix was to do move the code into files, similar to the following:

```
// ./src/interface.ts
import { ConcreteClass } from './concrete';

export interface BaseInterface {
   someFunction(): any;
}

export class Factory {
  static build(): BaseInterface {
     return new ConcreteClass();
  }
}

// ./src/base.ts
import { BaseInterface } from './interface';
class BaseClass implements BaseInterface {
  someFunction(): any {
    return true;
  }
}

// ./src/concrete.ts
import { BaseClass } from './base';
export class ConcreteClass extends BaseClass {
  someFunction(): any {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is 2018 and this is still the case... :(
using react, webpack cannot handle extends of classes well.

Comment: @Blaskovicz could you explain in detail how this works?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. The Factory Pattern is causing a circular reference. It seems that moving the factory to another file (and not a static method inside of a class that gets inherited) is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

I had faced similar issue, after checking all the workaround finally issue got resolved by deleting the node_modules folder and run `npm i`.