# TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, node.js

This problem has been causing me to lose my sanity for the last couple of days.

Here is my directory structure:

```
[src]
|- cmds/
|  |- Gh.js
|  \- Help.js
|- commands.js
|...
```

I am trying to import a class exported by `commands.js` into `Help.js` and `Gh.js` (and any other files I might add in the future). However, I keep getting an error:

```
class Gh extends _commands.Command {
                           ^
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

All of the files are being transpiled using Babel, with `env` set to `"node": "current"` and using the `wildcard` package. I have tried to set it for `"browser"` to see if it was an issue of it being too "advanced", but I got a different error about super functions (or something), which I assume is the same issue.

Here is the class being exported from `commands.js`:

```js
export class Command {
  constructor (msg) {
    this.id = msg.author.id
    this.msg = msg
  }
  action () {}
  get data () {
    return readData().user[this.id]
  }
  updateUserData (key, val) {
    updateUserData(this.id, key, val)
  }
  sendMsg (data) {
    sendMsg(this.msg, data)
  } 
}
```

...and here is `cmds/Gh.js`, one of the files that I am trying to import `Command` into:

```js
import {Command} from '../commands'

export class Gh extends Command {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg)
    this.desc = 'Returns GitHub repository link and exits'
  }
  action () {
    this.sendMsg('GitHub link: https://github.com/owm111/knife-wife')
  }
}
```

I tried putting `Command` into both of the `cmds/`, and they worked perfectly. However, when moving it back into `commands.js`, it broke again. I tried changing the path it is importing from from `../commands` to `./../commands`, `../commands.js`, `./../commands.js`; none worked. I moving `commands.js` into `cmds/`, still broke. I tried to `console.log(Command)` in both of the `cmds/`, but they both returned `undefined`.

All of this makes it look like is a problem with importing, but I cannot figure out what for the life of me. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176006/typeerror-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-function-or-null)

Comment: I get this same error just trying to run a sfdx command through the terminal. SFDX: Create project won't even work. I've reinstalled just about everything I can thing of; Npm LTS, Node, vscode, and the packages as well as independent installs and nothing seems to solve mine. Don't know if is related other than the message,but just thought I would comment.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409183/how-to-fix-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-constructor-or-null-nodejs/59916833#59916833](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409183/how-to-fix-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-constructor-or-null-nodejs/59916833#59916833)

Answer (score 59):

If anyone else sees this error, the first thing to look for is **circular dependencies**. Import file A into B, B into some other file C, and so on. If any of C through Z is imported into A, then JS will not be able to ensure that a file is defined at the time that another file needs it (and will not try to go back and fill in the blanks later).

This was likely the case here, since there was clearly other code not posted, and it only appeared when file dependencies were introduced. The problem exists **regardless of file structure**: the only structure guaranteed to avoid it is a single giant JS file. The solution is to ensure a strict tree structure of relationships between classes, and use factory methods or alternative communications like emitters to keep the couplings loose.

If you have more than a couple import / require statements, I recommend periodically running a checker like [Madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) to find and optionally visualize any loops before they become hard to undo.

```sh
npm install --save-dev madge
node_modules/madge/bin/cli.js --warning --circular --extensions js ./
```

Comment: Which is interesting, because I'm running the whole thing through ESBuild and still getting the error :/

Comment: Does ESBuild advertise circle-checking along with its fast bundling/minifying? Circular dependencies will sneak past most project-processing tools that are not designed to analyze a map of the whole file structure.

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure, I've never seen anything in that vicinity. I did notice, however, that the issue came from checking against a class which I didn't define a constructor for. It was defined in it's super class. Implementing it did the trick.

Answer (score 12):

As others have mentioned, this results from circular dependencies. I tried for hours to resolve it. Ultimately it was a tool called [dpdm](https://github.com/acrazing/dpdm) that worked wonders for me, finding 27 cycles and quickly leading to resolution. (I only had to solve a couple of those before the rest resolved as well.)

`yarn global add dpdm` or `npm i -g dpdm`

Then
`dpdm file.js` or `dpdm file.ts`

In my case this found a large number of cycles that Madge and manual inspection had failed to reveal. Great tool.

Comment: Wow. Brliliant tool. Just knocked it out of the park.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a simple fix for node.js. Remove export from your class and at the bottom of your file put this in it.

```
module.exports.Command;
```

Now if you want to use the command class anywhere you just need to put this in each file where you would like to use it.

```
var { Command } = require('Command.js');
```

Comment: I tried typing in what you said, but I got linter errors saying `'Command' is defined but never used.` and `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.`. I changed the line to `module.exports.Command = Command` and it got rid of the errors, but same issue. I removed the ` = Command` and disabled the linter and still, the same problem mentioned in the question. I don't think its making a difference because, as stated in the question, I am transpiling through Babel.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I made the dumb mistake of putting parentheses after extending React.Component like this:

```
class Classname extend React.Component() {
    ...
```

Removing the parentheses fixed the error.

Answer (score 4):

I was using **index.ts** to export class, interfaces, abstract classes.

In my case, the order of the **export dependency order** was wrong.

If B extends A, and on your **index.ts** you did the following, this will through the error mentioning A.

```
export { B } from 'somewhere';
export { A } from 'somewhere';
```

To fix that, you must maintain the order of dependencies like

```
export { A } from 'somewhere';
export { B } from 'somewhere';
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case: I was importing a non-existing class:

Counter.js:

```
import React, { Compontent } from 'react';

class Counter extends Compontent {
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Counter from './components/Counter';

function App() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Another cause can be that you use the following syntax (after copying a class from a declaration file (xxxx.d.ts) -> xxxx.ts

```
export declare abstract class Something {
```

should be (of course):

```
export abstract class Something {
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I upgraded to Angular 13 from 12. `ng update` did not update `webpack` to v5 and their upgrade checklist doesn't mention it being a retirement. Once I upgraded `webpack` to latest, the error went away for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with your node version

What i did was to uninstall my node version manager, re installed and used it to install all my node versions , did nvm use to select which one to use , in my case it was 14.17.3 ,
**ran npx react-native init**   command

That fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

I got this error that **"Sequelize TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null, NodeJS"** and solved it using that. If you have the same error, you can use the following solution that I've tried to explain it in code.

for example:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    // Modeling a table: Inheritance
    class Todo extends sequelize.Model {} // (!) Error

    // if you want to use the above line, add the following line to "lib\sequelize.js file
    // Sequelize.prototype.Model = Model; // add this line here

    class Example extends sequelize.Sequelize.Model { }

    Example.init({
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.STRING,
        status: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'todo',
        timestamps: true
    });

    return Example;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For people getting this error when using [JSweet](http://www.jsweet.org/) java to javascript transpiler, I was able to fix it by enabling the 'bundle' option, mentioned [here](https://github.com/lgrignon/jsweet-maven-plugin):

> Bundle up all the generated code in a single file, which can be used
>   in the browser. The bundle files are called 'bundle.ts',
>   'bundle.d.ts', or 'bundle.js' depending on the kind of generated code.
>   NOTE: bundles are not compatible with any module kind other than
>   'none'.

This is part of my POM which contains the 'bundle true' addition:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jsweet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsweet-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jsweet.transpiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <tsOut>target/ts</tsOut>
                    <outDir>target/js</outDir>
                    <candiesJsOut>webapp</candiesJsOut>
                    <targetVersion>ES6</targetVersion>
                    <module>none</module>
                    <moduleResolution>classic</moduleResolution>
                    <bundle>true</bundle>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-js</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jsweet</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Then re-run 'mvn generate-sources', and make sure that you change the index.html file to load the new bundle.js file:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Test page</p>
    <p id="target"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../webapp/j4ts-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../target/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on **Angular** "class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null" when running cypress and resolved it by changing the compiler options is tsconfig.json.

from:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./node_modules/*"            <== throws error
      ],
```

to:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./node_modules/"              <== correct
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Another common cause of this error is if you installed Node.js into an already existing folding of an older installation of Node.js.  Removing and reinstalling Node.js fixes that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone is facing this issue even though there is no circular dependency and using webpack then please add target:node in your webpack config file.

Comment: Other options for webpack target - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/