# "react-meteor-data" gives error with react 16

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I am using react 16 with meteor.
I am using react-meteor-data package for using "withtracker".
But this package gives this issue

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
at ReactMeteorData.jsx (packages/react-meteor-data/ReactMeteorData.jsx:162:36)
at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:322:7)
at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:224:14)
at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
at createContainer.jsx (packages/react-meteor-data/createContainer.jsx:1:210)
at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:322:7)
at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:224:14)
at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
at react-meteor-data.jsx (packages/react-meteor-data/react-meteor-data.jsx:1:139)
at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:322:7)
at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:224:14)
at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
at /home/amardeep/react-16/simple-todo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/react-meteor-data.js:330:15
at /home/amardeep/react-16/simple-todo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/react-meteor-data.js:337:3
at /home/amardeep/react-16/simple-todo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:411:36
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

What could be the possible reason.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I just write simple-todo app from meteor site. In third step it said to run "meteor add react-meteor-add" after that app crashed. When I remove this package it's working fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603541/typeerror-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-constructor-or-null

Comment: Thanks for the link but I could't understand. Now I am using ultimate-react-tracker instead of withtracker and remove the package react-meteor-data and its working fine.