# TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, discord.js, extends

I try to use Clear in my `index.js`, but the code doesn't work, it extends the class Clear by Moderation to get Moderation method.

**Full error:**

```js
class Clear extends Moderation {
                    ^
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chigu\SoftKr\Asuha-Discord-Universal-Bot\Src\Actions\Moderation\Commands\Clear.js:5:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chigu\SoftKr\Asuha-Discord-Universal-Bot\Src\Actions\Moderation\Moderation.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

*Clear.js*

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const {Moderation} = require("../Moderation");

class Clear extends Moderation {
    constructor(message, client) {
        super(message, client);
        this.command = "clear";
   } //methode and code
}

module.exports = {
    Clear
}
```

*Moderation.js*

```js
const {Clear} = require("./Commands/Clear");

class Moderation {
    constructor(message, client, staff, prefix) {
        this.message = message;
        this.client = client;
        this.staff = staff;
        this.prefix = prefix;
    } //methode and code
}

module.exports = {
    Moderation,
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176006/typeerror-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-function-or-null)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could it be a circular dependency issue? You're importing each class inside the other. Did you try removing this line from `Moderation.js`?

```
const {Clear} = require("./Commands/Clear");
```

Comment: Yeah, really thanks you that was a circular dependency!

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered the same error and did what was said, but there was no solution.

Then I installed 16.14.0 LTS from nodejs releases and the problem was solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).