# Typeerror: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or nulll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, class

I get the above error on runtime, I use Create-React-App with Typescript.

Here's my code:

`src/api/HttpClient.ts`

```
class HttpClient {
  public readonly instance: AxiosInstance;
  public constructor(baseURL: string) {
    this.instance = axios.create({ baseURL });
  }
}
export default HttpClient;
```

`src/api/auth/index.ts`

```
import HttpClient from "../HttpClient";
export class AuthService extends HttpClient {
  public constructor() {
    super("http://dev.api");
  }
  // API Calls
  public MakeHttpRequest = () => this.instance.get("/users");
}
```

Tried exporting by default `AuthService`, tried exporting `HttpClient` by name. Same error.

It compiles and runs fine only if both these classes are in the same file, which is not what I'm trying to achieve tbh.

EDIT:

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "watch": true,
    "outDir": "./built",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: did you try `import HttpClient from "../../HttpClient";`?

Comment: That's an incorrect path. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, my bad, counted the file as dir.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176006/typeerror-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-function-or-null)

Answer (score 1):

Found out I was circular importing a file. Closed.