# Angular Upgrade 8 to 11 version Error : Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I am upgrading Angular 8 to 11.
I getting below issue :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Module.4lR8 (main.js:sourcemap:59)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:sourcemap:80)
    at Module.etL5 (main.js:sourcemap:3115)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:sourcemap:80)
    at Module.A3+G (main.js:sourcemap:1039)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:sourcemap:80)
    at Module.ct+p (main.js:sourcemap:3011)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:sourcemap:80)
    at Module.ZAI4 (main.js:sourcemap:2897)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:sourcemap:80)
```

Please provide me solution for the above issue.

Details of Angular Version :

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.12
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.13

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.12
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.12
@angular/cdk                    11.2.12
@angular/cli                    11.2.12
@angular/http                   7.2.15
@schematics/angular             11.2.12
@schematics/update              0.1102.12
ng-packagr                      11.0.0
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.2
```

Comment: provide some more details, is there any class that you have extended??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176006/typeerror-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-function-or-null)

Comment: @Injectable()
export class UserService extends ServiceBase {
}



export abstract class ServiceBase {
}

Comment: same things are working fine in the angular 8

Comment: specify all details in your code, also provide details of methods in both the classes

Comment: @Injectable()
export class UserService extends ServiceBase {
 constructor( @Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient) {
        super(http);
    }
    load(s: string): Observable<Array<UserVO>> {
        return this.get(---);
    }
}

Comment: export abstract class ServiceBase {
 static onTokenExpired = new EventEmitter();
    static onTokenRefreshed = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

    protected get<T>(url: string, options?: any, ctor?: new () => BaseVO, resolveLater: boolean = false): Observable<T> {
        ....
    }

    protected post<T>(url: string, data: any, options?: any, ctor?: new () => BaseVO, resolveLater: boolean = false):Observable<T> { 
 -----
    }
}

Comment: export abstract class ServiceBase {
 static onTokenExpired = new EventEmitter();
    static onTokenRefreshed = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }

    protected get<T>(url: string, options?: any, ctor?: new () => BaseVO, resolveLater: boolean = false): Observable<T> {
        ....
    }

    protected post<T>(url: string, data: any, options?: any, ctor?: new () => BaseVO, resolveLater: boolean = false):Observable<T> { 
 -----
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

Try adding [@Directive()/@Component()](https://angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes) to base class

> Marking a an abstract class with @Directive() (no arguments) tells
> Angular that it should compile this class, creating a factory and
> wiring up any methods or properties that will be interacted with by
> Angular.

```
   @Directive()
   export abstract class ServiceBase { 
      static onTokenExpired = new EventEmitter(); 
      static onTokenRefreshed = new EventEmitter<string>(); 
      constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { } 
      protected get<T>(url: string, options?: any, ctor?: new () => BaseVO, resolveLater: boolean = false): Observable<T> { .... } 
      protected post<T>(url: string, data: any, options?: any, ctor?: new () => BaseVO, resolveLater: boolean = false):Observable<T> { ----- } 
    }
```

[For More Info](https://hackmd.io/@alx/S1XKqMZeS)

Comment: adding @Directive() does not solve the problem

Comment: Can you create stackblitz ?