# Every time I run npm I get this message - Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: npm

"Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null" comes up
every time I run npm here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfYMz.png)

Comment: Maybe this comment can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742533/14654948

Comment: You should include the full text of your error message in the post, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

I came into this same error on Monday morning. Perhaps it was overkill, but my solution was to uninstall npm, remove the `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/` directory, and reinstall npm. Everything appears functional now.

---

To be precise, this is the full error message I saw if I ran npm, like `npm --version`:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/dist/index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js:169:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

For what it's worth, I got this error under Arch Linux with a direct install of npm, not using `nvm`.

Comment: thank you, this worked for me, also on arch, installed via pacman, not nvm. my steps were (1) `sudo pacman -Rsc npm` (2) `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules` (3) `sudo pacman -S npm` (4) `npm i -g npm@latest` (5) `npm -v`

Answer (score 0):

Download fresh node js and press it to install after first next you will see option to remove the existing node js click on that and reinstall it the problem should be solved as it happens to me[image: option]