# After Angular upgrade to 16 ng s throws error - Class extends value undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-upgrade, angular-devkit

I have upgraded Angular from version 15 to 16
And also have upgraded all the dependency packages in my app to latest versions

After Npm i and on running ng serve it throws error as

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
See "C:\Users\rxq486\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-3pEwUo\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

My Package details on ng v

```
Angular CLI: 16.2.9
Node: 18.12.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.2.12
```

My package.json details

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.2",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^13.0.1",
    "@ngneat/transloco": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.43.3",
    "@videogular/ngx-videogular": "^8.0.0",
    "ajv": "^8.12.0",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^7.0.2",
    "angular-resize-event": "^3.1.1",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^16.1.0",
    "angular2-draggable": "16.0.0",
    "angular2-hotkeys": "^16.0.1",
    "angular2-virtual-scroll": "^0.4.16",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^3.33.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "esri-loader": "^2.15.0",
    "macaddress": "0.5.3",
    "math-random": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "mydatepicker": "^9.0.2",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-click-outside": "^9.0.0",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "ng2-right-click-menu": "0.0.16",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^11.0.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^16.3.9",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
    "original": "1.0.2",
    "panzoom": "^9.2.5",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.34.3",
    "sass.js": "^0.11.1",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.5.0",
    "sshpk": "1.18.0",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "tslib": "2.6.2",
    "underscore": "^1.13.6",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^8.2.5",
    "web3": "^4.2.1",
    "worker-timers": "^7.0.77",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1602.9",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.1001.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "schematics-scss-migrate": "^1.1.7",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  }
```

I tried downgrading Angular-devkit to previous 15v but then also same error

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176006/typeerror-class-extends-value-undefined-is-not-a-function-or-null?

Comment: Hi @Chellappanவ i have resolved the above circular dependency error. But now got many compilation errors for unknown elements after Angular 16 upgrade. Basically the components declared in AppModule are not identified
`
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'ui-switch'.
1. If 'ui-switch' is an Angular component and it has 'disabled' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ui-switch' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schema
.`

Comment: Have you upgraded all you dependencies to latest version?

Comment: Yes i have upgraded all packages to latest version. and those not compatible with ivy has been removed. Basically something seems broken from AppModule, when i import those unknown error components in SharedModule that error is gone. But it doesnt seem right way to fix.