Sens SMS with Twilio : Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
I'm trying to send an SMS with Twilio in Vue.js, except I get an error when I go to Tools -> Developer Tools.
<template>
 <div>
   <input type="text" v-model="to" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone">
   <textarea v-model="body" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   <button @click="sendSMS">Envoyer SMS</button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import twilio from 'twilio';

export default {
 data() {
   return {
     to: '',
     body: '',
     accountSid: 'VOTRE_ACCOUNT_SID_TWILIO',
     authToken: 'VOTRE_AUTH_TOKEN_TWILIO',
     twilioNumber: 'VOTRE_NUMERO_TWILIO',
   };
 },
 methods: {
   async sendSMS() {
     const client = twilio(this.accountSid, this.authToken);

     try {
       await client.messages.create({
         body: this.body,
         from: this.twilioNumber,
         to: this.to,
       });
       alert('SMS envoyé avec succès !');
     } catch (error) {
       console.error('Erreur lors de l\'envoi du SMS:', error);
       alert('Erreur lors de l\'envoi du SMS. Veuillez réessayer.');
     }
   },
 },
};
</script>


The error
twilio.js?t=17137716…939&v=b4dcae58:2609 Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
   at twilio.js?t=17137716…&v=b4dcae58:2609:36
   at ../../../node_modules/agent-base/dist/src/index.js (twilio.js?t=17137716…9&v=b4dcae58:2763:7)

I added npm install twilio
package.json : "twilio": "^5.0.4"

Did you give a try to some search? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44727578/8816585

agent-base is Node library, so is twilio, the error occurs in the relevant part of the code and suggests that a class that is specific to Node API doesn't exist.
A library like this cannot be safely run on client side because this would require to expose API keys that should remain private. This requires to use it in Node server and make requests to it from Vue application.
In cases of doubt, you should first check the library's documentation. Some Node libraries presume a developer already knows the context in which they should be used, but twilio documentation states this explicitly:

This library supports the following Node.js implementations:
Node.js 14
Node.js 16
Node.js 18
Node.js LTS (20)
TypeScript is supported for TypeScript version 2.9 and above.
Warning Do not use this Node.js library in a front-end application.
Doing so can expose your Twilio credentials to end-users as part of
the bundled HTML/JavaScript sent to their browser.


So how do I send SMS with Twilio in Vue.js?

"This requires to use it in Node server and make requests to it from Vue application". If you didn't develop server applications before, that's a necessity here. It's common for frontend apps to have Express server only to send contact emails or something like that that cannot be done on client side
