# How to solve TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null (Discord Bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

let me say this before explaining the question..I am a new guy in the field of coding, so idk much about this stuff( exactly why im asking this).So, I am developing a Discord Bot ( music bot ) and I am almost done with the code.( just 1 cmd for now).I encountered this error said in the title (TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null)when I used ' node . ' in my terminal. I will give the full thing that showed up in the terminal below. I use Visual Studio Code.

This is what poped up in the terminal when I used ' node . '-

````
C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\Discord bot\nodejs\index.js:76
module.exports = class PlayCommand extends Command { 
                                           ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\Discord bot\nodejs\index.js:76:44)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47```
````

So, I really hope someone can help me with this cause im stuck with my progression due to this error.

This is the part of the code where this error appeared

```
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'play',
      aliases: ['play-song', 'add'],
      memberName: 'play',
      group: 'music',
      description: 'Play any song or playlist from youtube',
      guildOnly: true,
      clientPermissions: ['SPEAK', 'CONNECT'],
      throttling: {
        usages: 2,
        duration: 5
      },
```

Looking forward for some kind help! Ty :)

Code-

````
const Client = new Discord.Client();
const { Structures } = require('discord.js');
const path = require('path');
const { prefix, token, discord_owner_id } = require('./config.json');

Structures.extend('Guild', function(Guild) {
  class MusicGuild extends Guild {
    constructor(client, data) {
      super(client, data);
      this.musicData = {
        queue: [],
        isPlaying: false,
        nowPlaying: null,
        songDispatcher: null,
        volume: 1
      };
      this.triviaData = {
        isTriviaRunning: false,
        wasTriviaEndCalled: false,
        triviaQueue: [],
        triviaScore: new Map()
      };
    }
  }
  return MusicGuild;
});

const client = new Discord.Client({
  commandPrefix: prefix,
  owner: discord_owner_id // value comes from config.json
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
  client.user.setActivity(`${prefix}play`, {
    type: 'WATCHING',
  
  });
});

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (___, newState) => {
  if (
    newState.member.user.bot &&
    !newState.channelID &&
    newState.guild.musicData.songDispatcher &&
    newState.member.user.id == client.user.id
  ) {
    newState.guild.musicData.queue.length = 0;
    newState.guild.musicData.songDispatcher.end();
    return;
  }
  if (
    newState.member.user.bot &&
    newState.channelID &&
    newState.member.user.id == client.user.id &&
    !newState.selfDeaf
  ) {
    newState.setSelfDeaf(true);
  }
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'general'); // change this to the channel name you want to send the greeting to
  if (!channel) return;
  channel.send(`Welcome ${member}!`);
});

const { Command } = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Youtube = require('simple-youtube-api');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const { youtubeAPI } = require('./config.json');
const youtube = new Youtube(youtubeAPI);

module.exports = class PlayCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'play',
      aliases: ['play-song', 'add'],
      memberName: 'play',
      group: 'music',
      description: 'Play any song or playlist from youtube',
      guildOnly: true,
      clientPermissions: ['SPEAK', 'CONNECT'],
      throttling: {
        usages: 2,
        duration: 5
      },
      args: [
        {
          key: 'query',
          prompt: 'What song or playlist would you like to listen to?',
          type: 'string',
          validate: function(query) {
            return query.length > 0 && query.length < 200;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  async run(message, { query }) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel) {
      message.say('Join a channel and try again');
      return;
    }

    if (message.guild.triviaData.isTriviaRunning == true) {
      message.say('Please try after the trivia has ended');
      return;
    }

    if (
      // if the user entered a youtube playlist url
      query.match(
        /^(?!.*\?.*\bv=)https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/.*\?.*\blist=.*$/
      )
    ) {
      const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(query).catch(function() {
        message.say('Playlist is either private or it does not exist!');
        return;
      });
      // add 10 as an argument in getVideos() if you choose to limit the queue
      const videosArr = await playlist.getVideos().catch(function() {
        message.say(
          'There was a problem getting one of the videos in the playlist!'
        );
        return;
      });

      // this for loop can be uncommented if you want to shuffle the playlist

      /*for (let i = videosArr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [videosArr[i], videosArr[j]] = [videosArr[j], videosArr[i]];
      }
      */

      for (let i = 0; i < videosArr.length; i++) {
        if (videosArr[i].raw.status.privacyStatus == 'private') {
          continue;
        } else {
          try {
            const video = await videosArr[i].fetch();
            // this can be uncommented if you choose to limit the queue
            // if (message.guild.musicData.queue.length < 10) {
            //
            message.guild.musicData.queue.push(
              PlayCommand.constructSongObj(
                video,
                voiceChannel,
                message.member.user
              )
            );
            // } else {
            //   return message.say(
            //     `I can't play the full playlist because there will be more than 10 songs in queue`
            //   );
            // }
          } catch (err) {
            return console.error(err);
          }
        }
      }
      if (message.guild.musicData.isPlaying == false) {
        message.guild.musicData.isPlaying = true;
        return PlayCommand.playSong(message.guild.musicData.queue, message);
      } else if (message.guild.musicData.isPlaying == true) {
        message.say(
          `Playlist - :musical_note:  ${playlist.title} :musical_note: has been added to queue`
        );
        return;
      }
    }

    // This if statement checks if the user entered a youtube url, it can be any kind of youtube url
    if (query.match(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/.+/)) {
      query = query
        .replace(/(>|<)/gi, '')
        .split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);
      const id = query[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i)[0];
      const video = await youtube.getVideoByID(id).catch(function() {
        message.say('There was a problem getting the video you provided!');
        return;
      });
      // // can be uncommented if you don't want the bot to play live streams
      // if (video.raw.snippet.liveBroadcastContent === 'live') {
      //   return message.say("I don't support live streams!");
      // }
      // // can be uncommented if you don't want the bot to play videos longer than 1 hour
      // if (video.duration.hours !== 0) {
      //   return message.say('I cannot play videos longer than 1 hour');
      // }
      // // can be uncommented if you want to limit the queue
      // if (message.guild.musicData.queue.length > 10) {
      //   return message.say(
      //     'There are too many songs in the queue already, skip or wait a bit'
      //   );
      // }
      message.guild.musicData.queue.push(
        PlayCommand.constructSongObj(video, voiceChannel, message.member.user)
      );
      if (
        message.guild.musicData.isPlaying == false ||
        typeof message.guild.musicData.isPlaying == 'undefined'
      ) {
        message.guild.musicData.isPlaying = true;
        return PlayCommand.playSong(message.guild.musicData.queue, message);
      } else if (message.guild.musicData.isPlaying == true) {
        message.say(`${video.title} added to queue`);
        return;
      }
    }

    // if user provided a song/video name
    const videos = await youtube.searchVideos(query, 5).catch(async function() {
      await message.say(
        'There was a problem searching the video you requested :('
      );
      return;
    });
    if (videos.length < 5 || !videos) {
      message.say(
        `I had some trouble finding what you were looking for, please try again or be more specific`
      );
      return;
    }
    const vidNameArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
      vidNameArr.push(`${i + 1}: ${videos[i].title}`);
    }
    vidNameArr.push('exit');
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#e9f931')
      .setTitle('Choose a song by commenting a number between 1 and 5')
      .addField('Song 1', vidNameArr[0])
      .addField('Song 2', vidNameArr[1])
      .addField('Song 3', vidNameArr[2])
      .addField('Song 4', vidNameArr[3])
      .addField('Song 5', vidNameArr[4])
      .addField('Exit', 'exit');
    var songEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embed });
    message.channel
      .awaitMessages(
        function(msg) {
          return (msg.content > 0 && msg.content < 6) || msg.content === 'exit';
        },
        {
          max: 1,
          time: 60000,
          errors: ['time']
        }
      )
      .then(function(response) {
        const videoIndex = parseInt(response.first().content);
        if (response.first().content === 'exit') {
          songEmbed.delete();
          return;
        }
        youtube
          .getVideoByID(videos[videoIndex - 1].id)
          .then(function(video) {
            // // can be uncommented if you don't want the bot to play live streams
            // if (video.raw.snippet.liveBroadcastContent === 'live') {
            //   songEmbed.delete();
            //   return message.say("I don't support live streams!");
            // }

            // // can be uncommented if you don't want the bot to play videos longer than 1 hour
            // if (video.duration.hours !== 0) {
            //   songEmbed.delete();
            //   return message.say('I cannot play videos longer than 1 hour');
            // }

            // // can be uncommented if you don't want to limit the queue
            // if (message.guild.musicData.queue.length > 10) {
            //   songEmbed.delete();
            //   return message.say(
            //     'There are too many songs in the queue already, skip or wait a bit'
            //   );
            // }
            message.guild.musicData.queue.push(
              PlayCommand.constructSongObj(
                video,
                voiceChannel,
                message.member.user
              )
            );
            if (message.guild.musicData.isPlaying == false) {
              message.guild.musicData.isPlaying = true;
              if (songEmbed) {
                songEmbed.delete();
              }
              PlayCommand.playSong(message.guild.musicData.queue, message);
            } else if (message.guild.musicData.isPlaying == true) {
              if (songEmbed) {
                songEmbed.delete();
              }
              message.say(`${video.title} added to queue`);
              return;
            }
          })
          .catch(function() {
            if (songEmbed) {
              songEmbed.delete();
            }
            message.say(
              'An error has occured when trying to get the video ID from youtube'
            );
            return;
          });
      })
      .catch(function() {
        if (songEmbed) {
          songEmbed.delete();
        }
        message.say(
          'Please try again and enter a number between 1 and 5 or exit'
        );
        return;
      });
  }
  static playSong(queue, message) {
    const classThis = this; // use classThis instead of 'this' because of lexical scope below
    queue[0].voiceChannel
      .join()
      .then(function(connection) {
        const dispatcher = connection
          .play(
            ytdl(queue[0].url, {
              quality: 'highestaudio',
              highWaterMark: 1 << 25
            })
          )
          .on('start', function() {
            message.guild.musicData.songDispatcher = dispatcher;
            dispatcher.setVolume(message.guild.musicData.volume);
            const videoEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setThumbnail(queue[0].thumbnail)
              .setColor('#e9f931')
              .addField('Now Playing:', queue[0].title)
              .addField('Duration:', queue[0].duration)
              .setFooter(
                `Requested by ${queue[0].memberDisplayName}`,
                queue[0].memberAvatar
              );
            if (queue[1]) videoEmbed.addField('Next Song:', queue[1].title);
            message.say(videoEmbed);
            message.guild.musicData.nowPlaying = queue[0];
            queue.shift();
            return;
          })
          .on('finish', function() {
            if (queue.length >= 1) {
              classThis.playSong(queue, message);
              return;
            } else {
              message.guild.musicData.isPlaying = false;
              message.guild.musicData.nowPlaying = null;
              message.guild.musicData.songDispatcher = null;
              if (message.guild.me.voice.channel) {
                message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave();
                return;
              }
            }
          })
          .on('error', function(e) {
            message.say('Cannot play song');
            console.error(e);
            message.guild.musicData.queue.length = 0;
            message.guild.musicData.isPlaying = false;
            message.guild.musicData.nowPlaying = null;
            message.guild.musicData.songDispatcher = null;
            message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave();
            return;
          });
      })
      .catch(function(e) {
        message.guild.musicData.queue.length = 0;
        message.guild.musicData.isPlaying = false;
        message.guild.musicData.nowPlaying = null;
        message.guild.musicData.songDispatcher = null;
        if (message.guild.me.voice.channel) {
          message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave();
        }
        return console.error(e);
      });
  }
  static constructSongObj(video, voiceChannel, user) {
    let duration = this.formatDuration(video.duration);
    if (duration == '00:00') duration = 'Live Stream';
    return {
      url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.raw.id}`,
      title: video.title,
      rawDuration: video.duration,
      duration,
      thumbnail: video.thumbnails.high.url,
      voiceChannel,
      memberDisplayName: user.username,
      memberAvatar: user.avatarURL('webp', false, 16)
    };
  }
  // prettier-ignore
  static formatDuration(durationObj) {
    const duration = `${durationObj.hours ? (durationObj.hours + ':') : ''}${
      durationObj.minutes ? durationObj.minutes : '00'
    }:${
      (durationObj.seconds < 10)
        ? ('0' + durationObj.seconds)
        : (durationObj.seconds
        ? durationObj.seconds
        : '00')
    }`;
    return duration;
  }
};

client.login(token);```

I did not know how to make this like a spoiler, so forgive me if it was done in the wrong way/ too long.
````

Comment: Have you made sure to import `Command`? Is it a Class?

Comment: I think it's a matter of missing import statement. You could also provide a certain part of your code, the so called "Minimum Reproducible Example",  so people can check into it.

Comment: As I said sir, Im a student and idk much about it..I made this whole stuff after spending days seeing videos on youtube and searching on google for specific stuff. (tbh idk what you mean by that, but Its a class.) Please help me with a consideration that i'm really new to these things. ty

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Am I supposed to post questions like this here in this site? Im totaly new to coding and this site as well, but I dont know here to ask help.

Comment: @AsadS Hey! Is this enough? 
module.exports = class PlayCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'play',
      aliases: ['play-song', 'add'],
      memberName: 'play',
      group: 'music',
      description: 'Play any song or playlist from youtube',
      guildOnly: true,
      clientPermissions: ['SPEAK', 'CONNECT'],
      throttling: {
        usages: 2,
        duration: 5
      },
      args: [
        {
          key: 'query',
          prompt: 'What song or playlist would you like to listen to?',
          type: 'string',

Comment: @AsadS continuation of the above given code -
validate: function(query) {
            return query.length > 0 && query.length < 200;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  async run(message, { query }) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel) {
      message.say('Join a channel and try again');
      return;
    }

Comment: Yes StackOverflow is the place to ask this kind of question. Note that you could "edit" your question and provide your code there, not here in the comment :). We would be happy to help, but please improve your question.

Comment: @AsadS Hey! I have provided the code ( till what I have done) in the question as you said. Hoping for a help! Ty mate :)

Comment: @Lolan It is still hard for me to debug your problem, could you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please. Anyway, could you check you are not doing "circular reference" in your code? Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312197/node-js-v6-2-0-class-extends-is-not-a-function-error/37312355#37312355